# Stream file from one http endpoint to another

Tags: go

I am trying to stream a file from one http endpoint to another, and avoid storing large files on disk. I thought I had working with this code, but it is creating empty files:

```
    // out, err := os.Create(key)
    resp, err := http.Get("http://source_url.com/_content/" + key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // now stream the file straight to the endpoint using put
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://dest_url.com/_content/"+key, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(key, res.ContentLength, res.Status)
```

Comment: The client code looks correct. See [this working example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9ajZEuuQ_o). Show the server code.

Comment: Check StatusCode of the Get response. Most likely it is not 200 and your response.Body is simply empty. BTW last line in your code prints content length of second server response ("PUT"), not the length of data you have posted.

Comment: I tested the code and it's working fine! maybe the problem is with the destination code (if it's yours)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, its appreciated. I will maybe compare the content length of the put and get as well as the status on each end.